# Faster alternative to travel to any location in the west?

Tags: earth, atmospheric-science, speed, relative-motion, aircraft

Suppose one needs to travel to Somalia from Indonesia(which are approximately at a distance of $4000$ miles from each other on the line of equator). To accomplish this task, I suggest the following method:

Design an airplane that can surpass the earth's atmosphere radially(~ $300$ miles thick) and stand still in the air till the landing point of Somalia is just about to arrive radially beneath the plane's stationary point(earth rotates from west to east) at which time instant, the landing process is initiated. In this way, the total time taken would be:

\begin{equation}
T=\frac{4000(mi)}{1000(mi/h)}  + \epsilon
\end{equation}
Here, $1000(mi/h)$ is speed of any point on earth's equator and $\epsilon$ is the small time the aircraft took to travel to and fro through the earth's atmosphere.

The total approximated journey time with this method would not exceed $6(hr)$ which is considerably smaller than the actual time taken of about $12(hr)$. My apprehension is why this technique is not being used to facilitate travelling between two different points when the absolute speed of the aircraft(w.r.t space) can be reduced to zero by surpassing the earth's atmosphere?

Comment: What type of engine would you use?

Comment: @Farcher Involvement of the type of engine used would be secondary. Firstly, I'm trying to figure out if the proposed idea has any kind of upfront physical flaw

Comment: As aeroplanes cannot reach a height of 300miles, I don't see how this works.  I you use rocket powered craft instead, you could likely get to Somalia much quicker than 4 hours.  In the '60s some preliminary work was done to show that you could use a "sub-orbital lob" to travel 12,000 miles in about an hour.

Comment: Of course it works in principle given that the rotational speed of the Earth at the Equator is 465 m/s but the problem is getting to your "stationary" position and staying there.

Comment: It doesn't need to get into the stationary position as long as it can travel west beyond Karman Line with some non-zero speed. @DrChuck I reckon reaching a height of 64 miles would suffice to overcome atmospheric drag

Comment: An ICBM can reach any point of the planet in 45 minutes. A plane can't "stand still" in either air or vacuum any more than a rocket can. All these objects have to travel on ballistic trajectories as soon as they turn of their propulsion.

Comment: Yes, the idea is deeply flawed. Whatever motive power is being used to arrange "standing still" (and it takes some any way you look at it) could be used to get you there). Various science fiction authors have proposed variation on what Heinlein calls "semi-ballistics" (which differ from the ICBMs that @CuriousOne mentions mostly in being able to come to a smooth landing) which is the right way to handle the situation. But the people proposing commercial space craft don't think they'll pay as travel yet.

Comment: I think I have a good answer to this, if someone could re-open it.

Comment: @akshay If no one reopens this, feel free to post it to space.stackexchange.com, where I'll answer it.

Comment: @barrycarter Did it already.

Comment: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/13866 now answered.